# Serialization and Events in ASP.NET SqlServer Session Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Hi i've a custom server control with some events in a class marked serializable, they are marked as NonSerialized.

```
 [field: NonSerialized]
   public event DropDownListtarget_PreRender DropDownList_PreRender;
```

But i've a asp.net application that use SqlServer Session mode and the session object results null when i'll try to retrieve it from the Session Object.

So, how i can store in a session this object? how i can solve this problem?

Note that in InProc Mode, everything works fine...

Thanks.

Comment: ASP.NET server controls are relevant in the context of `Page` server-side lifecycle - not as something stored in `Session`.

Comment: and so? that i have to do?

Comment: do not store server controls in `Session`

Comment: I'm not storing server control in session, but in postbacks i'm losing the object that contains the events

Comment: whose methods are assigned to these events?

Comment: There is a series of imagebuttons (generated dinamically) click that refer a specific event that i'm using to hook to click function.

Comment: methods of which class are used as event handlers for the events in question?